# Parse-server: how to force a specific user or a user group to reset their passwords?

Tags: parse-server

I know that it is possible to enforce password reset after a period of time using password policy (maxPasswordAge) but, what if an admin needs to force a password reset for all users or for one specific user in case, for example, of a security threat? Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just restart the server with an altered age

```
passwordPolicy : {
    validatorPattern : /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/,
    doNotAllowUsername : true,
    maxPasswordAge : 90,
    maxPasswordHistory : 5,
    resetTokenValidityDuration : 24 * 60 * 60
},
```